# Use redux action the dispatch is not working

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have combined my react redux.

Here is my App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { compose, createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import reducers from './src/reducers';
import AppContainer from './src/navigator'

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

const App: () => React$Node = () => {

  const store = createStore(reducers, {}, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk)));

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <AppContainer />   
    </Provider>     
  );
};

export default App;
```

src/reducers/index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import LoginReducer from './LoginReducer';

export default combineReducers({
  LoginRedux: LoginReducer
});
```

If I use my action `login()`, I can see `login action start`, but I can't see `dispatch start`

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { 
      Text, 
      View, 
      TouchableOpacity,
    } from 'react-native';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import { login } from '../actions';

    const LoginScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

      // console.log('see my test value', testValue)

      return (
        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity 
            onPress={() => {
              login();
            }
          }>
            <View>
              <Text>LOGIN</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>

        </View>
       </View>
      );
    }

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
      const { testValue } = state.LoginRedux;
      console.log('mapStateToProps testValue =>', testValue);
      return { testValue };
    };

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { login })(LoginScreen);
```

If I `console.log(dispatch)`, it will show dispatch is not defined.

```
import { LOGIN } from './types';

export const login = () => {
  console.log('login action start')
  return (dispatch) => {
    console.log('dispatch start');
    // console.log(dispatch);
    dispatch({ type: LOGIN, testValue: 'I am test' });
  };  
};
```

src/reducers/LoginReducer.js

```
import { LOGIN } from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  testValue: ''
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  console.log('reducer =>', action); // I can't see the console.log
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOGIN:
      return {
        ...state,
        testValue: action.testValue
      };
    default:
      return state;
    }
};
```

I have no idea why my action dispatch is not working. Do I set something wrong ?

Any help would be appreciated.

According to Zaki Obeid help, I update like this:
the action code:

```
export const login = () => { 
  console.log('login !');
  return { type: LOGIN }; 
};
```

the function component code:

```
import { login } from '../../actions';

export const SettingScreen = ({ navigation, login }) => {
  // return view code
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  // you will use this to pass it to the props of your component
  login: () => dispatch(login),
});

connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(SettingScreen);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*In LoginScreen component*

you will need to add mapDispatchToProps

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  // you will use this to pass it to the props of your component
  login: () => dispatch(login()),
});


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginScreen);
```

**Then**

you will need to destructure from the props as:

```
const LoginScreen = ({ navigation, login }) => {
  // your code
}
```

*In actions.js*

the way you use dispatch here requires a library `redux-thunk` and it's used for async calls.

and the normal action should do the job for you:

```
   export const login = () => ({
     type: LOGIN,
     testValue: 'I am test' 
})
```

I hope this is useful and will solve your problem,
Have a good day.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but how do I trigger another logic in `login()` ?
In your way, the `login()` just a plain object.

Comment: Yes,but If I want to add some logic code in action side. It is impossible right ? Because the `login()` just do one thing send data to reducer.

Comment: You can pass it like this:
`<TouchableOpacity 
            onPress={() => {
              login
            }
          }>`

Comment: You can write your logic inside the action for sure but make sure that it returns this object to the reducer. 
`
export const login = () => { // your logic return { type: LOGIN, testValue: "I am test" } };
`

Comment: Thanks again, I try your code but still gets login is not a function, I update  the code in my question. Can you take a look plz ?  I even comment out `import { login } from '../../actions';` still the same error.

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed that.
You should keep the import and execute the login in mapDispatchToProps:

`const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  // you will use this to pass it to the props of your component
  login: () => dispatch(login()),
});`

Comment: Thank you very much !  I still have to change my export way like `export default connect(...)`. It is working now.  Bless you Zaki. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

In a react-redux app, you obtain the dispatch function either from getting a hold of the store object directly (`store.dispatch`), or via the react-redux `connect` function, which will provide dispatch as an argument to a function you write and then later hook up to a component

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const mapStateToProps = ...

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        someHandle: () => dispatch(myActionCreator())
    }
}

export const connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent)
```

You can't just call dispatch out of thin air -- it's not a global function.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I have put my action inside `export default connect(mapStateToProps, { login })(LoginScreen);` , my `login()` return (dispatch) => { // some code... } , it is not correct ?

Comment: If I use extends Component instead of my function Component and use `this.props.login()`, it's working.  But how do I use it in my function component now ?

Comment: I see I missed that. I haven't seen an object passed in for mapDispatchToProps before. Perhaps try `dispatch => ({ login })` instead of just `{ login }`.

Comment: Sorry I'am confused with `dispatch => ({ login }) `instead of just `{ login }`. Do you mean I have to adjust my `login()` code ?  How ?

Comment: I fix the code and works now. Thanks you very much Faust.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using the login function directly. you will have to use the props. Just change the name for confusing and use through props.

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import LoginReducer from './LoginReducer';

export default combineReducers({
  LoginRedux: LoginReducer
});
If I use my action login(), I can see login action start, but I can't see dispatch start

    import React from 'react';
    import { 
      Text, 
      View, 
      TouchableOpacity,
    } from 'react-native';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import { login } from '../actions';

    const LoginScreen = ({ navigation, userLogin }) => {

      // console.log('see my test value', testValue)

      return (
        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity 
            onPress={() => {
              userLogin();
            }
          }>
            <View>
              <Text>LOGIN</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>

        </View>
       </View>
      );
    }

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
      const { testValue } = state.LoginRedux;
      console.log('mapStateToProps testValue =>', testValue);
      return { testValue };
    };

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { userLogin:login })(LoginScreen);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I try the code shows userLogin is not a function.